# Floating point in UNIX using bash Shell

Tags: unix

Please help me to find out this, I am very new to UNIX,
My code is really can't get the right answer...

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

echo -n "How many number : "; read num
for ((i=0; i<$num; i++));
do 
    echo -n "Enter your number : "; read number 
total+=$(echo "${number}" | bc)
echo "${total}"

done
```

Comment: #! /usr/bin/env bash

echo -n "How many number : "; read num
for ((i=0; i<$num; i++));
do 
 echo -n "Enter your number : "; read number 
total+=$(echo "${number}" | bc)
echo "${total}"

done

Comment: Please edit your question instead of putting what is missing in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo -n "Enter your numbers: "
read numbers
total=$(echo "$numbers" | sed 's/ \+/ + /g' | bc)
echo "The total is $total"
```

Sample use:

```
Enter your numbers: 4 6 2.47
The total is 12.47
```

**MORE:** In your script, the problem was the line `total+=$(echo "${number}" | bc)`.  This fixes it:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
total=0
echo -n "How many number : "; read num
for ((i=0; i<$num; i++));
do 
    echo -n "Enter your number : "; read number 
    total=$(echo "$total + ${number}" | bc)
    echo "${total}"
done
```